# Best way to add an individual image to pdf form letter

Tags: images, pdf

I want to add an individual image to a static pdf.
Like I have 200 individual images and one pdf that is always the same. Then I want to say something like 2 inch top and 3 inch left and then the programm will place the image on this position and in the end I have 200 pdfs. Which software can solve this problem best?
Thank you.

Comment: The answers to this might help: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12794/use-an-artboard-as-a-template-exporting-multiple-versions-with-an-image-swap If you've got access to Indesign I'd suggest looking into Data Merge with a spreadsheet of 200 file locations (I've not personally used that feature enough to be able to offer a step-by-step though).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using whatever mail merge functions you might have on hand. In many programs, you can set up the merge to load a variably named graphic in a specific location, and the location is a data field in the merge record.

In windows, an easy way to get the filename(s) and paths is to select the ones you want, hold shift and right click, this will give you a few normally hidden options, one of which is called "copy as path". Then open a text file and paste the filenames into it. Another way is to redirect the output of a directory listing to a text file using the shell.

For the form document for the merge, you set the unchanging pdf as a watermark, 100% size, no blend or fade. When you run the merge, you want to select the option to save each record as an individual document.